# How to disable a mobile broadband device

Tags: drivers, devices, mobile-broadband

I am using a dell latitude E5250 which comes with support for a SIM card.
On bootup I get a message "The mobile broadband device cdc-wdm0 requires a SIM PUK before it can be used"
I dont need this and I want to disable this device. How can this be done?

Comment: Probably bios settings might hv that option..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this, after entering BIOS-Wireless setting, and disabling the WWAN/GPS device

Eventually had to uninstall the modemmanager as well to get rid of this popup for good